# Eclipse - How can I open a sql file?

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse, file

I am a beginner in Java Programming and on Eclipse.
 I have recently downloaded a java project on the internet, and when I try to execute it, it works at the beginning, but when I try to add a item in the data base the following error is displayed in the console:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I've downloaded :

> Data Tools Platform SQL Development
>   Tools org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.feature.feature.group

And I've also added my sql files by doing these instructions:

> New -> Others -> SQL Developpement -> SQL File -> Paste ( the
>   downloaded sql code)

Please can someone help me ?

Comment: Search on web for jdbc driver and download jar file and include it in eclipse project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to stick with Eclipse, I've found HSQLDB to work well with it. It's a free, very quick download.This would, however, replace MySQL in the project you downloaded and probably wouldn't be a good first go.

However, if you'd instead like to start from scratch with tutorials on the basics, then work your way up to SQL I suggest HSQLDB. http://hsqldb.org/

To include HSQLDB in your first project within Eclipse, right click your project in the project list within `Eclipse > Build Path... > Libraries tab > Add External JARs...` then select the HSSQL jar file you downloaded.

Again, this is if you're going to start from scratch in building your first program. I'm suggesting this because it's precisely the path I went down to get my feet wet with Java, Eclipse, and database handling.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention how you've already tried to solve this one. When you encounter some type of Exception, *always* look up what it means. They don't tend to be thrown at random.

In this case, you don't seem to have the MySQL driver on the project's **Java Build Path**. You might want to spend some time familiarizing yourself with the [concepts](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-build-classpath.htm?cp=1_2_1_0) you'll be working with, but at minimum, you need the MySQL driver jar to be in the project. Once you have that, right-click on it from inside of the **Package Explorer** View and add it to the **Java Build Path**.

There are also some very good [tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/article.html) you can look at. Developing software is *never* intuitive. Don't give up.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I don't find the Package Explorer View ...

Comment: Check the Window menu in the menu bar for a way to open or show Views, and more.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" is not in your classpath.  This means you need to install mysql support libraries. Making sure Eclipse (actually the java plugin) is configured properly can be a bit of a nightmare.

If you are very new to java development, it may be better to start with Netbeans, JDeveloper, or IntelliJ.  These tend to "just work" compared to Eclipse. I think IntelliJ is the most intuitive.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you're right it's actually a nightmare, I have to use Eclipse, create a Inventory management system for Monday...